# Get last id selected when timer reached using jquery and php

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

Hello guys i hope you can help me with my problem I'm building a CRUD in my Sales category.

The scenrios are:

1. If the user hover a specific row, its comments and a comment box will appear below.Usingthe jquery fadeIn()
2. And the user may enter his/her comment to that specific row.

   My problem is if I hovered down accidentally the mouse it points to other comments. So i created a timer for that in which that if the user hovered the mouse in that row for greater than in 3 seconds the comments for that row will appear no matter how many hover i hover the rows.

   $(function(){

   ```
       var counter = 0;
       var myInterval = null;


       $(".hover_comment").hover(function(e){  //this is the first hover with an ID
           counter = 0;
           myInterval = setInterval(function(){
               ++counter;
               console.log(counter);
           }, 1000);

           var salesid = $(this).find('span').text(); //SET IT TO VARIABLE
           $(".comment_boxes").hide();
           setTimeout(function(){$(".comment_box_"+salesid).fadeIn()}); 

           $('#txt_id').val(salesid); //SHOW THE COMMENT FORM
           $(this).find(".tempid").val();
           $("#comment_add") .show(); 


       },function(e){ //HERE'S THE FUNCTION WHEN I MOUSEOUT
               //CALL AGAIN
               var salesid = $(this).find('span').text();
               $(".comment_boxes").hide();
               setTimeout(function(){$(".comment_box_"+salesid).fadeIn()}); 

               $('#txt_id').val(salesid);
               $(this).find(".tempid").val();
               $("#comment_add") .show(); 

               clearInterval(myInterval);

               if(counter > 3){   //IF TIMER REACHED GREATER THAN TO 3 SECONDS THE ID SHOULD BE PLACE IN A VARIABLE AND DISPLAY ITS CONTENTS
                   //alert(salesid);

                   var thisid = salesid;
                   $(".comment_boxes").hide();
                   setTimeout(function(){$(".comment_box_"+thisid).fadeIn()}); 

                   $('#txt_id').val(salesid);
                   $(this).find(".tempid").val();
                   $("#comment_add") .show(); 

               }else{
                   //IF NOT CONTINUE TO HOVER
               }
       });
   ```

   });

That's my code I hope you can help me.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it's right from Usability POV. What if following scenarios are considered.

1. If user hovers any column for 3 seconds; pop up the comment section and a link on pop up; Do u want to add a comment?
2. On clicking yes, disable the page only comments section will be visible and user can post their comments.
3. On submitting the comment, enable the old logic for hovering for 3 secs.

and thus repeat the flow....

From usability POV this might be the right way to go, of-course be open for other suggestions also. If you want to add anything to this approach or correct it, please do it..... That way we might learn something new.